# Why does $\int_0^y dx \;\frac{e^{x^2}}{2}=5$ give $y\approx1.841$ as an answer?

Tags: integration

> Find a $k$ such that $\int_0^k dx \;\frac{e^{x^2}}{2}=5$

The point here is to use some kind a numeric integration, as I don't know anything about nonelementary antiderivatives. Therefore I made use of the rectangle method, so if $f(x)=\frac{e^{x^2}}{2}$, then

$$\int_0^k dx \;\frac{e^{x^2}}{2}\approx f(0.5)+f(1.5)\approx 5.39$$ which means that $k\approx 2$ and $k\lt2$.

This is all well and fine and there probably exists a better method to find the value of $k$ - but my own method made me feel like I was a physician or something, so of some intuitive reason I chose to write

$$\int_0^y dx \;\frac{e^{x^2}}{2}=5$$ into Desmos, which yielded $y\approx1.841$. ~$1.841$ is the correct answer. See this picture:

[image]

I checked this for $\int_2^kdx\;x^2=1/3x^3\mid_2^8=168$. $\int_2^ydx\;x^2=1/3x^3\mid_2^8=168$ should yield $y=8$. This can easily be checked graphically, which yields $y=8$ as an answer.

My problem is that I don't know what I have done.

1. What is the method/ type of integration called?
2. What is it that I have done mathematically, can you elaborate/ give more details?

Comment: Re 1., your question is about Desmos? Re 2., you said it yourself: you used  (a very crude version of) the rectangle method.

Comment: @Did I was blinded by the variable $y$, and didn't consider that for example $y=k$.

Comment: Is there a peculiar reason for not formulating the problem as *find a numerical method for solving $$\int_{0}^{k}\exp(x^2)\,dx = 10$$ with respect to $k$* ?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio My autism got in the way, otherwise this question would never have been asked to begin with, if you know anything about that peculiar diagnosis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=e^{x^2}$ is a convex function growing really fast, hence in order to find an initial approximation of the positive solution $k$ it is better to apply a substitution first.
$$\int_{0}^{k}\exp\left(x^2\right)\,dx =\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{k^2}\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx =\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{\exp(k^2)}\frac{du}{\sqrt{\log u}}.$$
To find a numerical solution of 
$$ \int_{1}^{T}\frac{du}{\sqrt{\log u}} = 20 \tag{A}$$
is a bit easier. By integration by parts
$$  \int_{1}^{T}u\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{u}\,du}{\sqrt{\log u}}=2T\sqrt{\log T}-\int_{1}^{T}\sqrt{\log u}\,du$$
hence $T_0=20\sqrt{\log 20}$ is a not so bad approximation of a solution of $(A)$.
 By invoking Newton's method and the trapezoid method for numerical integration,
$$ T_{n+1} = T_n - \sqrt{\log T_n}\left(-20+\int_{1}^{T_n}\frac{du}{\sqrt{\log u}}\right) \tag{B}$$
we get $T_1\approx 29.654$ and $T_3\approx T_2\approx 29.706$, then
$$ k\approx \sqrt{\log T_2} \approx 1.84157. \tag{C}$$

Comment: A bit too advanced for me, I am reading mathematics at a Swedish gymnasium level. But your answer is appreciated anyways!

Answer (score 2):

> For some intuitive reason I chose to write 
>   $$\int_0^y dx \;\frac{e^{x^2}}{2}=5$$ into Desmos, which yielded $y\approx1.841$. ~$1.841$ is the correct answer.

When you write $\displaystyle \int_0^y dx \;\frac{e^{x^2}}{2}=5$ as an equation into Desmos, you have to note that this only has one free variable, $y$. Desmos is smart enough to solve this equation for $y$, leading to some solution $y = c$.

But $y = c$ is just the plot of a straight line, which is the line that you see.

---

This is really no different than if you'd typed $\sqrt{y} = 2$ into Desmos and see a line at $y = 4$.

Comment: Hmm... yes of course. I was blinded by the variable $y$ and didn't consider that $y$ for example can be written as $y=k$.